# Where is the error in my code? syntax error, unexpected token "," (PHP)

Tags: php, html, syntax-error

I am a total beginner on PHP so that is why I can't find what the error is... it seems very simple but I can't find it, this is the part of my code that is giving me trouble:

```
function invalidRUT($username) {
$result;
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/"), $username) {
    $result = true;
}
else {
    $result = false;
}
return $result;
}
```

And the error message is:
syntax error, unexpected token "," (lin 15, col.5)

Comment: **Just a typo**. `preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/"), $username)` should be `preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $username)`

Comment: `function invalidRUT($username) {return !preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $username);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
(fixed code)

```php
function invalidRUT($username) {
$result;
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    $result = true;
}
else {
    $result = false;
}
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you accidentally wrote "," in your code and it caused an error, please delete or replace the ","

Comment: Thank you a lot for trying to help me!, sadly, I already tried that and it was not the solution, but as I said, thank you so much anyways for your efforts on helping me!